# How to perform ANOVA on the result of different polynomial regression models with different levels of degree using a for loop

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R and I think my problem is quite simple but I cannot seem to work it out. I've looked at similar problems on here but I can't seem to get a solution to work for my specific problem.

I'm using the Wage data set that comes as part of the ISLR package to try and model wage as a function of age of differing polynomial degrees.

```
  library(ISLR) 
attach(Wage)
```

I'm performing regression onto wage with age up to degree 10 and then I want to apply the anova test to each model and investigate the results. The closest I have got is this;

```
  for (i in 1:10) {
    fit[[i]] <- lm(wage~poly(age, i) , data = Wage)
    result[[i]] <- aov(as.formula(paste(fit[i], "~ wage")))
  }
```

which results in this error;

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = as.formula(paste(fit[i], "~ wage")),  :
```

invalid type (list) for variable 'list(coefficients = c(`(Intercept)` = 111.703608201744, `poly(age, i)` = 447.067852758315), residuals = c(`231655` = -19.3925481434428, `86582` = -28.2033380861585, `161300` = 17.4500251413464, `155159` = 42.5676926169455, `11443` = -42.0253778623369, `376662` = 7.21810821763668, `450601` = 56.7036617292801, `377954` = 8.79783605559716, `228963` = 8.18131081863092, `81404` = 10.197404483506, `302778` = 3.61466467869064, `305706` = -24.4688637359983, `8690` = -16.9669134309657, `153561` = 25.4168784550536,      `449654` = 14.807739524331, `447660` = -27.2938944517631, `160191` = -25.1943075097583, `230312` = 95.773820436023, `301585` = 7.84450555272621, `153682` = -9.27460094600634, `158226` = 91.9620415895517, `11141` = -59.5891117312741, `448410` = -49.3664897185768, `305116` = 50.6467028157233, `233002` = -14.5085059894098, `8684` = 161.240161560035, `229379` = -28.0716427246922, `86064` = -40.6412633049063, `378472` = -5.75413931818888, `1

Any help would be greatly appriciate and apologises for being such a R noob.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you can do:

```
library(ISLR) 
attach(Wage)
fit <- vector("list",10)
result <- vector("list",10)
for (i in 1:10) {
    thisForm <- paste0("wage~poly(age, ",i,")")
    fit[[i]] <- lm(thisForm , data = Wage)
    result[[i]] <- aov(fit[[i]])
  }
```

Above I created the formula so that you can see it in the fit / aov object, instead of having i.

Note that the lm fit is already in the aov object, meaning, you can get coefficients, predict and do things you need with lm directly on the aov object. You don't need to store the lm fit separately:

```
coefficients(result[[1]]) ; coefficients(fit[[1]])
 (Intercept) poly(age, i) 
    111.7036     447.0679 
 (Intercept) poly(age, i) 
    111.7036     447.0679
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, and your explanation was greatly helpful to my understanding. Thanks alot.

Comment: Cool. Glad it was useful for you :)